# Pandas select time series with at least five positive values in a row

Tags: pandas

Here is a dataset for time series forecasting. Some time series columns have a lot of zeros and I want to ignore them.

```
   import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2019-01-06 00:00:00','2019-01-13 00:00:00','2019-01-27 00:00:00',
                            '2019-02-03 00:00:00','2019-02-10 00:00:00','2019-02-17 00:00:00',
                            '2019-02-24 00:00:00','2019-03-03 00:00:00','2019-03-10 00:00:00',
                            '2019-03-17 00:00:00'],
                    'timeseries1': [None, None, None, 5, 10, 5, 10, 5, 8, 15], 
                    'timeseries2': [4, 4, None, 4, None, None, 5, 9, 6, 12], 
                    'timeseries3': [None, 5, 9, 6, 12, 10, None, None, None, None],
                    'timeseries4': [None, None, 9, None, 10, 5, 8, None, 7, None],
                    'timeseries5': [None, 5, 5, 10, 5, 8, 15, 9, None, None]
                            })
df = df.set_index('date')
df
```

I want to select the columns containing at least five positive values in a row. Thus, the results would be three separate time series values as follows.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I personally would recommend to split the date into the columns `date` and `time` but keep the `timestamp`.

First, make sure, that the timestamp column is type of date.

```
df['timestamp'] == df['date']
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.date
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.time
```

The advantage is that you can easily filter your data.

Another method is the pandas method `between_time` (see [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html))

```
df.between_time('0:00:01', '23:59:59')
```

To filter the pandas dataframe, you can use following code:

```
dfTimeseries1 = df[df['timeseries1'] > 0, ['date', 'timeseries1']]
```